# How to create folders and files from paths given in text file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file named `creating.txt`. In this file, each line has a path.

- If line starts with `D` it means that I have to create directory.
- If line starts with `F`, I have to create a file.

For example:

```
D:/root/F1/Cat1
F:/root/F1/file1.txt
D:/root/F1/Cat1/Cat2
```

I need to go line by line, first check if first letter is `D` or `F`, then ignore the `:` and the first letter and accordingly create a file or directory based on given path. If first letter in line is not `D` or `F`, just ignore the line.

Also if the file already exists I'm not allowed to create another one.

I tried using `awk`:

```
path=`awk { print } creating.txt`
touch $path
```

But the problem is this reads the whole file (not line by line) so there have to be only one line. Also I don't know how to ignore `D:` and `F:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with two 2 one-liners

I reproduced your input :

```
$ cat creating.txt
D:/root/F1/Cat1
F:/root/F1/file1.txt
D:/root/F1/Cat1/Cat2
```

You can use this to create the Directories

```
$ for path in `grep ^D creating.txt | cut -d: -f2`; do mkdir -p "$path";done
```

Then, for files

```
$ for file in `grep ^F creating.txt | cut -d: -f2`; do touch "$file";done
```

Explanation:
The grep, will select the lines beginning [as I used ^] by D (or F)
The cut, will catch the 2nd field using ':' as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `bash` *script* that will do as you asked:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ (.):(.*) ]]
    [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == D ]] && mkdir -p "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == F ]] && [[ ! -d ${BASH_REMATCH[2]%/*} ]] && mkdir -p "${BASH_REMATCH[2]%/*}"
    [[ ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} == F ]] && touch "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done < creating.txt
```